# How does this "bit set" work in C?

Tags: c, int, bit-manipulation

```
unsigned int    error_bits =       

                 ( X && Y )
                 | ( A == TRUE)                         << 1
                 | ( B == TRUE)                         << 2
                 | ( C == TRUE && 
                     D == TRUE)                         << 4;
```

I believe the general concept here is to set each of the 32 bits to true or false based on certain conditions - with each bit representing an error of something.

With the syntax above, I'm a  little confused as to what is being set, shifted and where/why.

Any clarification is helpful.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. The layout of the bits after the line are:

```
Bits X-5: 0
Bit 4: (C == TRUE && D == TRUE)
Bit 3: 0
Bit 2: B == TRUE
Bit 1: A == TRUE
Bit 0: (X && Y)
```

From most significant to least significant bit.
Propably something like this would be more readable (a matter of taste):

```
unsigned int error_bits = 0;

if( X && Y )     
    error_bits |= 1;

if( A == TRUE )     
    error_bits |= 2;

if( B == TRUE )     
    error_bits |= 4;

if( C == TRUE && D == TRUE )     
    error_bits |= 16;
```

Answer (score 2):

A == TRUE will evaluate to 1 if A is TRUE. 1 << 1 is 2, or an integer with only the 2nd bit set (numbered from least-significant). 1 << 4 is 16, or an integer with only the 5th bit set.

Answer (score 1):

`error_bits` value is set according to:

- Least significant bit (b0) is set when (X && Y) is true , i.e., both X and Y are true.
- b1 is set when A is true
- b2 is set when B is true
- b3 is clear
- b4 is set when both C and D are true